# How to properly transpile react module with babel, and how to properly handle imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I think that I'm having a problem with imports being redeclared within my transpiled index.js file

I'm transpiling some react es6 components into a single index.js file. These components are then imported into another projects by running 'npm install /path/to/myComponents'

When I import these components into my main project, I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Identifier '_interopRequireDefault' has already been declared
...
> 53 | function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }
...
```

This line does show up multiple times in my index.js in a chunk of code that looks like this

```
var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

var _componentX = require("./ComponentX.js");

var _propTypes = _interopRequireDefault(require("prop-types"));

var _this = void 0;

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }

var ComponentY = function ComponentY(props) {
```

I want to fix how I transpile the code so that this either doesn't happen, or I just ignore redeclarations, they are all the same anyway.

my src folder, where my react components are, contains an index.js file, and a components folder with 3 Components inside it. Each of these component contains

```
import React from 'react';
import propTypes from 'prop-types'
```

And two of them import the third component

---

### **Possible solution**

I'm pretty sure the solution involves changing something about the line "build": `"./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js".` But I don't know how to do this.

These are the files within my Components folder, not my main project folder(which imports the components folder.)

---

### **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

### **package.json**

```
{
    "name": "myComponent",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
    }
}
```

### **webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' // THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE! :mindblow: I wasted more than 2 days until realize this was the line most important in all this guide.
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react' // this line is just to use the React dependency of our parent-testing-project instead of using our own React.
  }
};
```